# Hazel cast : Cluster giving the error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I am using hazelcast and trying to connect to different machines for session sharing. Hazelcast is getting started successfully on one machine. but when i try to start it on another machine it is giving me the following error 
"Incompatible joiners! expected: multicast, found: tcp-ip"

```
@Bean
public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
    MapAttributeConfig attributeConfig = new MapAttributeConfig()
            .setName(HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
            .setExtractor(PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());

    Config config = new Config();
    NetworkConfig network = config.getNetworkConfig();

    JoinConfig join = network.getJoin();

    join.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    // config.setProperty("hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size", "2");
    join.getTcpIpConfig().addMember("10.31.24.26").addMember("10.31.25.159").setRequiredMember(null)
            .setEnabled(true);

    config.getMapConfig("spring:session:sessions").addMapAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
            .addMapIndexConfig(new MapIndexConfig(HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, false));

    return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
}
```

Can some one please help me with this ?

Regards.
Hemal.

Comment: You sure you're running the same code on both machines ? Can you post the logs from both

Comment: hi @NeilStevenson yes i am sure about that.

Comment: @NeilStevenson Below are the errors i am seeing on both the machines.      Machine 1 : [10.31.24.26]:5702 [dev] [3.7.1] Received an invalid join request from [10.31.25.159]:5701, cause: Incompatible joiners! expected: multicast, found: tcp-ip                                                                                              Machine 2 :  "Incompatible joiners! expected: multicast, found: tcp-ip"

Comment: Can you post the full start-up logs from both machines please. If the same code runs on both, the same config should occur on both. Logs will prove.

Comment: The fact machine 1 is using port 5702 not 5701 suggests another Hazelcast process is already running.